# Using popup to send emails stopping the message from being sent

Tags: php, forms, alert

I've got a simple pop up form which sends an email.

What I want my form to do is to

1. Display alert
2. Close the pop up window - after pressing `submit` button.

This is the code that represents my submit button

```
 <input type='image' id="submit" src="images/submit.png" onclick="show_alert(); closeWin()" />
```

It displays error and closes the window but somehow it stops the message from sending. If I remove the 'closeWin()' part then the window won't close.

Has anyone got any suggestion what I can do to fix it?

**EDITED**

```
//alert on form submit

function show_alert()
{

alert("Thank you. We'll be in touch soon to process your claim.");

}

//close window

function closeWin()
{

 window.close();

}
```

Comment: can you post some code? There is probably a "return false" statement in your closeWin method or a typo.

Comment: isn't the problem with this line? `onclick="show_alert(); closeWin()"` You are calling `closeWin();` right before calling `show_alert();` so basically there is nothing wrong with your code, only with your logic =)

Comment: How is a window supposed to submit a form when it's no longer open?

Comment: Oh right, so it is supposed to be: `onclick="closeWin(); show_alert()"`. I thought that whatever comes after = sign takes place first, so first it would display alert and then close the window :P
// Just to add - I'm a total n00b in java world

Comment: Nope, reversed order doesn't solve it. He he. The window will close but alert is not displayed and form not submitted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to submit the form, you have to delay the window closing until after the the form submit. The easy way would be to place the `window.close()` code in the server response for the form.

Note that using alerts is not so nice, you should consider other ways to inform the user.
The standard way is to place this message in the form response page, together with an "OK" button that would close the popup.